# The threads are not printing in a sequence in my program

Tags: java, multithreading

I have the program below to sequence the 3 threads.
For example first the first thread should print followed by second and then third thread.
Bu the program below is not actually doing that and printing some random sequence.
I have seen some programs on stackoverflow itself which execute and try to print in sequence.

But I am really trying hard to understand why the program below is not working and what is the thing I am not able to understand.

```
package my.tutorial.java;

import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class SequenceThreads {
    private static final Object lock = new Object();

    static class Task implements Runnable {
        private final String tName;
        private final int turnId;
        private static int nextTurn = 1;

        public Task(String tName, int turnId) {
            this.tName = tName;
            this.turnId = turnId;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                synchronized (lock) {
                    if (nextTurn != turnId) {
                        try {
                            // System.out.println(tName + " went waiting   " + nCount);
                            lock.wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                    // System.out.println(tName + " went waiting");
                    System.out.println(tName + " Executed  ");
                    ++nextTurn;
                    if (nextTurn == 4)
                        nextTurn = 1;

                   // System.out.println(nextTurn);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    lock.notify();
                }


            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        final Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
        //AtomicInteger nCount = new AtomicInteger(1);
        final Task task1 = new Task("T1", 1);
        final Task task2 = new Task("T2", 2);
        final Task task3 = new Task("T3", 3);
        executor.execute(task1);
        executor.execute(task2);
        executor.execute(task3);
    }
}
```

The expected result should be

```
T1 Executed
T2 Executed
T3 Executed
T1 Executed
T2 Executed
T3 Executed
```

But the actual result is

```
T1 Executed  
T2 Executed  
T1 Executed  
T1 Executed  
T3 Executed  
T3 Executed  
T1 Executed  
T3 Executed  
T3 Executed
```

Comment: the issue is that each thread has its own nextTurn. so they aren't actually waiting for their turn they are seeing if it'd their turn then waiting some amount of time and incrementing turn order and trying again. that state needs to be maintained outside of the thread.

Comment: @AlexandarPetrov turning bad answers into bad comments? how is this helpful to OP?

Comment: @mavriksc the field nextTurn is static and not specific to a thread.

Comment: `notify` *chooses* some *random* Thread to wakeup... and you are not checking after the `wait` if it is the correct one

Comment: 1 it's not up to us to question why they are doing it really. 2. i would guess that this is to learn about synchronization and deadlock, in multi threaded programs.

Comment: @AlexandarPetrov: sometimes it's a good idea to understand the programs you wrote.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Thanks for suggestion. But even if I use notifyAll, I get the random threads printing.
And nextTurn == turnId, then only the thread will xecute else will wait so out of all notified thread one will execute which has its turn i.e turnId == nextTurn

Comment: it is not a suggesting, it is the explanation why you are getting *random* sequences - `notifyAll` won't change much on that

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger but that also does not seem to work

Comment: how not? is it not notifying the (all) thread(s) as documented ("*If any threads are waiting on this object, one of them is chosen to be awakened. The choice is arbitrary and occurs at the discretion of the implementation*")

Comment: maybe you should  check the documentation of `wait`(also because of "*A thread can wake up without being notified, interrupted, or timing out, a so-called spurious wakeup*") .

Comment: @NathanHughes  what if instead of just specifying order, another condition was checked for in order to determine if appropriate information was available to be processed. that seems like a totally viable situation. so how about we help the person instead of debating the validity of the question.

Comment: Why don't you dedicate a turn to a thread. So T1 executes only turns with reminder 1 T2 with reminder 3 and T3 with reminder 0.

Comment: When a thread wakes up if the reminder is not what it expects it continues sleeping.

Answer (score 3):

Your code has 2 problems.

1.) You check if it's a thread's turn to print with the `nextTurn != turnId` in an `if` statement. That means that if a thread reaches this `if`, it's not the thread's turn, it waits once, can then be woken up again, it might *still* not be that thread's turn, but it doesn't check again and just continues executing out of order.

To fix that, turn this `if` into a `while`.

2.) `notify()` does not wake up all waiting threads. That means that you might get a situation where the wrong thread is woken up, check's and sees that it's not the thread's turn yet, goes to sleep again, and then the `notify()` call is never reached, so the right thread is never woken up. In that case we are dealocked, unless a spurious wakeup occurs.

For that you can use `notifyAll()` instead.

After fixing those 2 things I'm seeing the expected output:

```
T1 Executed  
T2 Executed  
T3 Executed  
T1 Executed  
T2 Executed  
T3 Executed  
T1 Executed  
T2 Executed  
T3 Executed
...
```

Comment: actually I believe it would be enough for the wrong thread to be waken up only once (not over and over again) for all to get stuck for ever (disregarding the spurious and rare wakeups)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Yeah, good point, in that case the `notify()` call is never reached again, and the right thread is never woken up.

Comment: @ThomasWeller it sure is not trivial - documentation of `wait`: "*This method causes the current thread (referred to here as T) to place itself in the wait set for this object and then to **relinquish any and all synchronization claims** on this object*"  - otherwise NO Thread would be EVER able to call `notify` to wake a waiting thread since both need the lock

Comment: Ok, thanks. Think I understood it now. I'll check if I can do the same in C#, using `Monitor.Enter()` and `Monitor.Exit()`while I'm in a `lock` statement.

Comment: @JornVernee thanks a trillion especially for the second point. :).

It really helped me understand things more better.